# Find mean difference by group on variables using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Supposed, I have the following `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x1 = c(1:12), x2=c(21:32))
```

Then, I create bins by user-specified intervals using the following:

```
dt[,intx1:=cut(x1, breaks = c(-Inf, 4, 9, Inf))]
```

return,

```
    x1 x2    intx1
 1:  1 21 (-Inf,4]
 2:  2 22 (-Inf,4]
 3:  3 23 (-Inf,4]
 4:  4 24 (-Inf,4]
 5:  5 25    (4,9]
 6:  6 26    (4,9]
 7:  7 27    (4,9]
 8:  8 28    (4,9]
 9:  9 29    (4,9]
10: 10 30 (9, Inf]
11: 11 31 (9, Inf]
12: 12 32 (9, Inf]
```

I am trying to find the mean difference between bins and variable:

```
dt[, mux1_grp:=mean(x1), by = intx1][,mux1_pop:=mean(x1)][,mux1_diff:=mux1_grp-mux1_pop]
dt[,`:=`(intx1=NULL, mux1_grp=NULL, mux1_pop=NULL)]
```

The return is:

```
    x1 x2 mux1_diff
 1:  1 21      -4.0
 2:  2 22      -4.0
 3:  3 23      -4.0
 4:  4 24      -4.0
 5:  5 25       0.5
 6:  6 26       0.5
 7:  7 27       0.5
 8:  8 28       0.5
 9:  9 29       0.5
10: 10 30       4.5
11: 11 31       4.5
12: 12 32       4.5
```

However, my original data contain several variables (e.g., x1, x2,...,x20).
So, I have to repeat the same procedure for x2 as follows:

```
dt[,intx2:=cut(x2, breaks = c(-Inf, 25, 28, Inf))]
dt[, mux2_grp:=mean(x2), by = intx2][,mux2_pop:=mean(x2)][,mux2_diff:=mux2_grp-mux2_pop]
dt[,`:=`(intx2=NULL, mux2_grp=NULL, mux2_pop=NULL)]
```

My final output will be:

```
    x1 x2 mux1_diff mux2_diff
 1:  1 21      -4.0      -3.5
 2:  2 22      -4.0      -3.5
 3:  3 23      -4.0      -3.5
 4:  4 24      -4.0      -3.5
 5:  5 25       0.5      -3.5
 6:  6 26       0.5       0.5
 7:  7 27       0.5       0.5
 8:  8 28       0.5       0.5
 9:  9 29       0.5       4.0
10: 10 30       4.5       4.0
11: 11 31       4.5       4.0
12: 12 32       4.5       4.0
```

How can I improve this code? Note that each variable has different user-specified intervals

Comment: Regarding the other variables, you are grouping each time separately on each of those right?  In that case you may need a `for` loop because the grouping variable changes everytime.

Comment: Fyi, `dt[,\`:=\`(int=NULL, mu_grp=NULL, mu_pop=NULL)]` can be `dt[,c("int","mu_grp","mu_pop") := NULL]`. Regarding your actual question, I'd recommend going to long format, with the x1..x20 in a single column using `melt`. It's covered in the fifth vignette: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in a compact one-step option (though it may be not that optimal when compared to the OP's method (from @Frank's comments)

```
dt[, mu_diff := mean(x) - mean(dt$x), by = .(cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 4, 9, Inf)))][]
#    x    mu_diff
#1:  1 -3.8636364
#2:  2 -3.8636364
#3:  3 -3.8636364
#4:  4 -3.8636364
#5:  5  0.3863636
#6:  6  0.3863636
#7:  7  0.3863636
#8:  9  0.3863636
#9: 10  4.6363636
#10:11  4.6363636
#11:12  4.6363636
```

---

If there are many variables (it is not clear whether we use the same `breaks` in `cut` or not for different columns - assuming that it is the same), we can loop through the columns (in the reproducible example below, two variables 'x1' and 'x2' are showed), specify the `.SDcols` by the numeric index of the column, grouped by the `cut` of the subsetted column, we assign the new column as the difference between the  `mean` of the values within the group and the `mean` of the entire column.

```
nm1 <- paste0("mu_diff", seq_along(dt1))
for(j in seq_along(dt1)){
  dt1[, (nm1[j]) := mean(.SD[[1L]]) - mean(dt1[[names(dt1)[j]]]), 
      by = .(cut(get(names(dt1)[j]), breaks = c(-Inf, 4, 9, Inf))) ,
              .SDcols = j][]
 }
```

**Update** - Suppose if the `breaks` for `cut` variable is *different* for each column, place it in a `list` and get that `list` element inside the `for` loop with the indexing.

```
brkLst <- list(c(-Inf, 4, 9, Inf), c(-Inf, 10, 14, Inf))
for(j in seq_along(dt1)){
  dt1[, (nm1[j]) := mean(.SD[[1L]]) - mean(dt1[[names(dt1)[j]]]), 
      by = .(cut(get(names(dt1)[j]), breaks = brkLst[[j]])) ,
              .SDcols = j][]
 }
```

Checking the output with OP's new data ('dt2')

```
brkLst2 <- list(c(-Inf, 4, 9, Inf),  c(-Inf, 25, 28, Inf))
nm1 <- paste0("mu", names(dt2), "_diff")
for(j in seq_along(dt2)){
   dt2[, (nm1[j]) := mean(.SD[[1L]]) - mean(dt2[[names(dt2)[j]]]), 
  by = .(cut(get(names(dt2)[j]), breaks = brkLst2[[j]])) ,
          .SDcols = j][]
}

dt2
#    x1 x2 mux1_diff mux2_diff
# 1:  1 21      -4.0      -3.5
# 2:  2 22      -4.0      -3.5
# 3:  3 23      -4.0      -3.5
# 4:  4 24      -4.0      -3.5
# 5:  5 25       0.5      -3.5
# 6:  6 26       0.5       0.5
# 7:  7 27       0.5       0.5
# 8:  8 28       0.5       0.5
# 9:  9 29       0.5       4.0
#10: 10 30       4.5       4.0
#11: 11 31       4.5       4.0
#12: 12 32       4.5       4.0
```

#### data

```
dt1 <- data.table(x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12))[, x2 := x1 + 5][]
#OP's changed dataset
dt2 <- data.table(x1 = 1:12, x2=21:32)
```

Comment: Because of the GForce optimization on grouped `mean`, the OP's approach may have better performance. You can see it with the OP's example and `verbose` on: `dt[, mu_grp:=mean(x), by = cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 4, 9, Inf)), verbose=TRUE]` So there's a tradeoff involved when avoiding the temporary var.